# getting input from URL

Tags: php

I made a script with the PHP Teamspeak Framework to check if a user is online.

I want to get input from the URL, so `index.php?in=myname`

My script:

```
<?php
global $input;
$input = $_GET["in"];

        function OnlineTS() {

            require_once("/ts3/libraries/TeamSpeak3/TeamSpeak3.php");

            $ts3_VirtualServer = TeamSpeak3::factory("serverquery://ts.mydomain.com:10011/?server_port=9987");

            global $input;

            if ($input != "") {
                $client = $ts3_VirtualServer->clientGetByName($input);

                echo "<h2>" . $input . ' is online on teamspeak in channel "' . $ts3_VirtualServer->channelGetById($client['cid']) . '"</h2>';
            }
        }   
        OnlineTS();
?>
```

trying `index.php?in=myname` (who is online) doesn't work.

Can I get some help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```
$input = $_REQUEST["in"];
echo $input;
```

Comment: why may $_GET not work here and $_REQUEST do? nonsense